# Matlab - Creating large covariance matrix (350x350) from covariance function with an integral

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance, integral, large-data

I am working on a project where I would like to create a covariance matrix from a covariance function that contains a double integral. As my data has 350 entries, this matrix becomes 350x350.

My problem is that while the one without integral runs in a couple seconds

WITHOUT INTEGRAL

```
k_function = @(x01,x02) hyp(1)^2*exp(-0.5*(x01-x02).^2/hyp(2)^2); 
K = bsxfun(k_function, x1,x2) + hyp(3)*eye(length(x2),length(x1));
```

The one with the integral takes almost an hour to complete. Any ideas on how I could achieve the same outcome with a less computationally intense method?

WITH INTEGRAL

```
k_function = @(x01,x02) hyp(1)^2*exp(-0.5*(x01-x02).^2/hyp(2)^2);
for i = 1:length(x1)
    for j = 1:length(x2)
        K(i,j) = integral2(k_function,0,x1(i),0,x2(j));
    end
end
```

Edit:

hyp - array containing the 3 hyperparameters of the covariance function (so essentially constants during the creation of the matrix)

Edit2: -> Using the symmetrical property (still slow)

```
k_function = @(x01,x02) hyp(1)^2*exp(-0.5*(x01-x02).^2/hyp(2)^2);
for i = 1:length(x1)
    for j = 1:i
        K(i,j) = integral2(k_function,0,x1(i),0,x2(j));
    end
end

K = triu(K,1)' + K;
```

Thanks,

Matyas

Comment: Could you provide the `hyp` function? As a first step you could take advantage of the symmetry of the covariance matrix.

Comment: hyp is a variable (actually 3 variables)-> hyperparameters of the covariance function. The whole thing is ran through an optimisation method (Maximum Likelihood Estimation) after being created. (I'll edit the question with that)

Comment: I think the integral could be calculated analytically; [integral(exp((x-y)^2))](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=exp%28%28x-y%29%5E2%29&random=false) and [integral(erfi(y-a))](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=erfi%28x-a%29&random=false) seems to be feasible.

Comment: @Arpi So you mean this in my case? : [Integrate(a^2*Exp((-0.5*(x - y)^2)/b^2), x)](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=a^2*exp%28-0.5*%28x-y%29^2%2F%28b^2%29%29&random=false)

And then [Integrate(1.2533141373155003*a^2*b* Erf((0.7071067811865475*(y - 1.*x))/b), x)](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1.2533141373155003*a^2*b*+Erf[%280.7071067811865475*%28y+-+1.*x%29%29%2Fb]&random=false)

Sorry, first time link formatting :D

Comment: Yes, something like that, of course you should apply the integration limits, and you can easily verify it with numerical integration.

Comment: @Arpi I cant seem to figure out how to translate this to matlab. I could calculate the indefinite integral through WA, but then I somehow need to evaluate it. Were it a singe integral it would be easy, however with a double integral i am unsure. 
The x01 and x02 arrays in my code are identical (essentially x02=x01=0:1:350). This means the first row and column of the matrix will be all 0, and the rest should be positive if I am correct.

Comment: Do it in two steps, first treat `x02` as a constant and perform the integration (single), apply the integration limits, perform the second integration (single). [Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Double_integral)